# Understanding C++0x lambda captures

Tags: lambda, c++11

In one of the recent C++0x drafts (n3225.pdf) we can find 5.1.2/10:

> The identifiers in a capture-list are looked up using the usual rules for unqualified name lookup (3.4.1); each such lookup shall find a variable with automatic storage duration declared in the reaching scope of the local lambda expression. An entity (i.e. a variable or this) is said to be explicitly captured if it appears in the lambda-expression’s capture-list.

That *seems* rather restrictive to me. For example, it *seems* to me that the following things are disallowed:

```
int global;

struct s {
    int x;
    void memfun() {
        [x,global]{};
    }
};
```

since `x` is not necessarily a variable with automatic storage and neither is `global`. Note that the intention of this capture clause is to let the lambda object store a *copy* of `x` and `global` which might be desirable in case they are changed at a later stage. I am already aware of an alternative:

```
int global;

struct s {
    int x;
    void memfun() {
        int copyx = x;
        int copyglobal = global;
        [copyx,copyglobal]{};
    }
};
```

But this boils down to extra copies and additional boiler plate just to capture `x` and `global` as copy.

Also, i cannot find anything conclusive in the latest drafts about what happens if we name a local reference in the capture clause:

```
int main() {
    int  i = 0;
    int &r = i;
    assert([r]{return &r;}() != &i);
}
```

Does the lambda object "copy a reference" or "copy an int"? If it captures the referred object by copy, this can save us the additional copies from the previous work-around.

GCC apparently supports all these examples and stores a copy of an int in the last case (which is desirable, IMHO). But I would like to know whether this is in fact the intended behaviour according to the C++0x drafts or just a compiler-extension respectivly an implementatin bug.

**Edit:**

templatetypedef pointed out 5.1.2/14 which explains what happens when a reference is named in a capture-clause. As far as I can tell, this allows us to use the following work-around for the first example:

```
int global;

struct s {
    int x;
    void memfun() {
        auto& cx = x;
        auto& cglob = global;
        [cx,cglob]{};
    }
};
```

Tia,
sellibitze

Comment: Note: C++14 extended the set of possible capture clauses

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From what you've posted it seems like your first example is illegal since neither captured variable has automatic duration.  <strike>However, you can easily fix this.  To capture the data member, you can just capture this, and the global doesn't need to be captured as you can just reference it directly.</strike>

**EDIT**: As you pointed out, this will not create a local copy of the value you want to capture.  <strike>To capture these variables while making a copy, you can capture this, then explicitly create a local copy of the data member inside of the lambda.</strike>

As for the second question about capturing references, §5.1.2/14 says that capturing a variable of reference type by copy will create a copy of the value referenced instead of creating a copy of the reference.  Thus the lambda will have its own copy of the value that the reference was referencing when it was created.

Comment: The point of naming `x` and `global` in the capture clause was to let the lambda object store a *copy*. This might be desirable in case `::global` and `s::x` change their values. So, no, capturing `this` does not lead to the intended behaviour.

Comment: You are correct; I just updated my answer.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out 5.1.2/14. Looks like we can introduce local references to non-auto variables as a work-around if we are interested in capturing other things by copy.

Comment: Making a copy inside the lambda is still different from making a copy at the time of lambda creation.  Not that it's difficult to do so, just can't use your proposal "solution".