# C++ lambda won't call the destructor on members captured by value

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, lambda, llvm

I've been badly bitten by this strange behavior of lambdas under XCode today - after trying to trace several memory leaks in iOS around the code, I've narrowed it down to this (and similar) snippet(s) where I assign the ownership of something to a deferred task using a shared pointer:

```
void DBStorage::dispose(std::shared_ptr<DataChunk>& dc)
{
    backgroundQueue.queueTask([=]() {
        assert( dc.use_count() == 1 );

        if (dc->isDirty()) {
            //store to disk
        }
    });
}
```

(Note that the shared pointer's use count is always 1 when the lambda is run)

After execution, this task is null-ified with `pendingJob = nullptr;` which I expected to call the destructor of all the captured-by-value objects, and consequently `DataChunk`'s destructor.
However, it looks like that under XCode/LLVM  `lc`'s destructor is never called; calling its dtor explicitly, using `mutable`, and deleting the `std::function` with a simple `delete` didn't work either.

Is this standard behavior?
I can of course manually call `dc.reset()` and it works as expected, but this quite makes the point of using a shared pointer moot.

---

**Solution**
Apparently, it is a [known gcc bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529177/capturing-reference-variable-by-copy-in-c0x-lambda?lq=1).

---

**Contrib**

Stand-alone sample with output from Xcode 5.0.2/clang 3.3

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

void fnRef(std::shared_ptr<int>& ptr)
{
    auto lambda = [=]() { std::cout << ptr.use_count() << ':' << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; };
    lambda();
}

void fnVal(std::shared_ptr<int> ptr)
{
    auto lambda = [=]() { std::cout << ptr.use_count() << ':' << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; };
    lambda();
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptr(new int);
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        fnVal(ptr);
    std::cout << '\n';

    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        fnRef(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

**LLVM/GCC Output**

```
3:void fnVal(std::shared_ptr<int>)::<anonymous class>::operator()() const
3:void fnVal(std::shared_ptr<int>)::<anonymous class>::operator()() const
3:void fnVal(std::shared_ptr<int>)::<anonymous class>::operator()() const
3:void fnVal(std::shared_ptr<int>)::<anonymous class>::operator()() const
3:void fnVal(std::shared_ptr<int>)::<anonymous class>::operator()() const
3:void fnVal(std::shared_ptr<int>)::<anonymous class>::operator()() const
3:void fnVal(std::shared_ptr<int>)::<anonymous class>::operator()() const
3:void fnVal(std::shared_ptr<int>)::<anonymous class>::operator()() const
3:void fnVal(std::shared_ptr<int>)::<anonymous class>::operator()() const
3:void fnVal(std::shared_ptr<int>)::<anonymous class>::operator()() const

2:void fnRef(std::shared_ptr<int> &)::<anonymous class>::operator()() const
3:void fnRef(std::shared_ptr<int> &)::<anonymous class>::operator()() const
4:void fnRef(std::shared_ptr<int> &)::<anonymous class>::operator()() const
5:void fnRef(std::shared_ptr<int> &)::<anonymous class>::operator()() const
6:void fnRef(std::shared_ptr<int> &)::<anonymous class>::operator()() const
7:void fnRef(std::shared_ptr<int> &)::<anonymous class>::operator()() const
8:void fnRef(std::shared_ptr<int> &)::<anonymous class>::operator()() const
9:void fnRef(std::shared_ptr<int> &)::<anonymous class>::operator()() const
10:void fnRef(std::shared_ptr<int> &)::<anonymous class>::operator()() const
11:void fnRef(std::shared_ptr<int> &)::<anonymous class>::operator()() const
```

[**IDEOne.com Output for same code**](http://ideone.com/uPLKH0)

```
3:fnVal(std::shared_ptr<int>)::__lambda1
3:fnVal(std::shared_ptr<int>)::__lambda1
3:fnVal(std::shared_ptr<int>)::__lambda1
3:fnVal(std::shared_ptr<int>)::__lambda1
3:fnVal(std::shared_ptr<int>)::__lambda1
3:fnVal(std::shared_ptr<int>)::__lambda1
3:fnVal(std::shared_ptr<int>)::__lambda1
3:fnVal(std::shared_ptr<int>)::__lambda1
3:fnVal(std::shared_ptr<int>)::__lambda1
3:fnVal(std::shared_ptr<int>)::__lambda1
2:fnRef(std::shared_ptr<int>&)::__lambda0
2:fnRef(std::shared_ptr<int>&)::__lambda0
2:fnRef(std::shared_ptr<int>&)::__lambda0
2:fnRef(std::shared_ptr<int>&)::__lambda0
2:fnRef(std::shared_ptr<int>&)::__lambda0
2:fnRef(std::shared_ptr<int>&)::__lambda0
2:fnRef(std::shared_ptr<int>&)::__lambda0
2:fnRef(std::shared_ptr<int>&)::__lambda0
2:fnRef(std::shared_ptr<int>&)::__lambda0
2:fnRef(std::shared_ptr<int>&)::__lambda0
```

**Visual Studio 2013 Output**

```
3:fnVal::<lambda_67137a3f93ee478c018cc7068004c9fd>::operator ()
3:fnVal::<lambda_67137a3f93ee478c018cc7068004c9fd>::operator ()
3:fnVal::<lambda_67137a3f93ee478c018cc7068004c9fd>::operator ()
3:fnVal::<lambda_67137a3f93ee478c018cc7068004c9fd>::operator ()
3:fnVal::<lambda_67137a3f93ee478c018cc7068004c9fd>::operator ()
3:fnVal::<lambda_67137a3f93ee478c018cc7068004c9fd>::operator ()
3:fnVal::<lambda_67137a3f93ee478c018cc7068004c9fd>::operator ()
3:fnVal::<lambda_67137a3f93ee478c018cc7068004c9fd>::operator ()
3:fnVal::<lambda_67137a3f93ee478c018cc7068004c9fd>::operator ()
3:fnVal::<lambda_67137a3f93ee478c018cc7068004c9fd>::operator ()

2:fnRef::<lambda_70f241d4201227663d23c74be170d302>::operator ()
2:fnRef::<lambda_70f241d4201227663d23c74be170d302>::operator ()
2:fnRef::<lambda_70f241d4201227663d23c74be170d302>::operator ()
2:fnRef::<lambda_70f241d4201227663d23c74be170d302>::operator ()
2:fnRef::<lambda_70f241d4201227663d23c74be170d302>::operator ()
2:fnRef::<lambda_70f241d4201227663d23c74be170d302>::operator ()
2:fnRef::<lambda_70f241d4201227663d23c74be170d302>::operator ()
2:fnRef::<lambda_70f241d4201227663d23c74be170d302>::operator ()
2:fnRef::<lambda_70f241d4201227663d23c74be170d302>::operator ()
2:fnRef::<lambda_70f241d4201227663d23c74be170d302>::operator ()
```

Comment: What version of the compiler are you using?  There was a bug in GCC that a capture-by-value of a reference was a reference.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529177/capturing-reference-variable-by-copy-in-c0x-lambda

Comment: `clang --version` says,`Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.75) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)` - that definitely looks possible, however first copying `dc` in the local scope and then capturing the copy didn't work either!

Comment: Tom, you're not seeing things I *just* had the same problem writing up an example code for this, and now I can't reproduce it for the life of me. When I say "just" I mean 5 minutes ago. I changed a `std::cout` location, and now its no longer happening, and changing it *back* doesn't matter. And no, I'm not making this up. I'll see i I can do it again. (and I'm running the same Xcode/clang you are, btw).

Comment: I noobed out when trying to copy to the local scope... `auto local = lc` will not copy the pointer! The code suggested by @Yakk works :)

Comment: @Tom89 Maybe so, but you may find the output I contributed to your question interesting. I certainly did.

Comment: Yes, it seems to agree with the idea that references are copied by reference, and that there seems to be a bit of disagreement on what this should do. Visual Studio 2013 agrees with IDEOne and outputs 3 and 2.

Comment: Oh its worse than that. I'm hesitantly confident its a defect. I have one more update (and I'll try and cut down the output size, sorry about that).

Comment: I've added the VS output, but now it's a tad long :)

Comment: @Tom89 Maybe. I've seen worse. =P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted by @DaveS this could be a [known gcc bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529177/capturing-reference-variable-by-copy-in-c0x-lambda?lq=1) -- captured references are stored as references.

A good rule of thumb when working with stored lambdas is to avoid `=`, as stored state should be treated with care.

```
void DBStorage::dispose(std::shared_ptr<DataChunk>& dc)
{
  std::shared_ptr<DataChunk> data_to_store = dc;
  backgroundQueue.queueTask([data_to_store]() { // maybe add `,this` to the capture list
    assert( data_to_store.use_count() == 1 );
    if (data_to_store->isDirty()) {
      //store to disk
    }
  });
}
```

or:

```
void DBStorage::dispose(std::shared_ptr<DataChunk> data_to_store)
{
  backgroundQueue.queueTask([data_to_store]() { // maybe add `,this` to the capture list
    assert( data_to_store.use_count() == 1 );
    if (data_to_store->isDirty()) {
      //store to disk
    }
  });
}
```

as a second bit of unsolicited advice, `std::function`s are not lambdas, and calling one `theLambda` is misleading.

Comment: Thanks, I noobed out when trying this by myself as I wrote `auto data_to_store = dc` getting yet another reference! Also, `theLambda` is actually called `pendingJob` in the actual code, but I'll edit the OP to make it less misleading :)

Comment: And... how so a known GCC bug applies as-is to a completely different compiler? That's quite strange, and looks like disagreement on the spec?

Comment: @Tom89 Wait, `auto data_to_store = dc;` should be a value -- `auto` deduces like a `T` parameter.  /puzzle

Comment: I stand corrected again, `auto data_to_store` does indeed work. Never trust "proof" you remember from multi-hour bug hunts! Probably something else was broken when I tried then, who knows.

Comment: Considering that `[&]` is even worse, one might recommend avoiding implicit captures altogether (which I think is probably your intent).

Comment: @Casey `[&]` only when creating a lambda that dies (with all copies) before the end of the current scope.  `[vars,explicit]` when creating a persistent lambda.  `[=]` when writing throw-away code or in the middle of refactoring.

Comment: "A good rule of thumb when working with stored lambdas is to avoid `=`," That doesn't make sense. With stored lambdas it *only* makes sense to use `=` -- you cannot use `&`.

Comment: @newacct `[=]` -- avoid.  `[list,variables,explicitly]` -- all good.  Implicit capture of persistant state is dangerous with non-smart pointers, including `this`, everywhere.